# Ubuntu install error(stuck on error screen)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I am having an issue when trying to install ubuntu on my PC. I already have Windows running on my PC but wanted to install Ubuntu on a separate NVME that I installed but when I get to the grub screen and select try or install Ubuntu, I get two error messages.

1. config failed, hub doesn't have any ports(err-19)
2. nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset

PC - ASUS ROG STRIX B650E-e, AMD 7950x3d, Gigabyte RTX 4090oc, Trident Gskill DDR5 64GB

I have 4 separate hardrives: 3 NVME and 1 SATA.

When I get the error messages I have to turn off the computer to be able to access BIOS again. I am trying to boot off a USB with the latest version of Ubuntu 22.04.03. Could it be that the hardware I have isn't supported or am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mention "*latest version of Ubuntu*" which is the 2023-October release, ie. Ubuntu 23.10, but then mention an updated ISO of Ubuntu 22.04(.3) from 2022-April, thus you're not using the *latest*, just an updated ISO with package upgrades of the older release. You also didn't specify which Ubuntu product (Server? Desktop? and if using a later release there are two ISOs using different installers available for Desktop systems). Did you try *safe graphics* option?  (*as it shows in your unstated Ubuntu 22.04.3 product*)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a clean install or dual boot installation?

Also, before installing, first Try, if try is working fine and do not show any error then you will be able to install.

If above does not work then remove all your extra drives, leave it with one nvme and SATA and install it on any disk you want to. After installation you can install removed drives.

Let me know if it works.

Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to do a dual boot setup but with Windows on one drive and Ubuntu on another. The try option doesn't work at all. As soon as I select the "try or install option" it sends me to the error screen after a few seconds. I was thinking of taking out the 4090 and try it with the IGPU on the 7950x3d but not 100% sure if this is even compatible.

Comment: You install virtual machine like Virtualbox or VMWare on your windows and try to install it, if it fails on virtual machine also then it is not compatible with your hardware.

Comment: So I got it to install by removing the RTX 4090. It still get the ports error on boot but it loads a few seconds afterwards. Now I'm tasked with getting ot to boot with the 4090. When I have both the Igpu and 4090 connected it's boots fine on the IGPU but the 4090 just shows my splash screen and says Ubuntu. I'm going to try and add/update the nvidia drivers to see if that works.

Comment: Glad to hear that, as you can see splash screen, it would take some time to load drivers and copy respective temporary bootable files. i hope you are installing Ubuntu Desktop version, not the Ubuntu Server version.